# How to express "greater than any number including NULL" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Like `column>0` in `INT` column means **"greater than `0` or `NULL`"**. Is there way to write statement which will say **"greater than any number or `NULL`"**?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
(column == NULL) OR (column IS NOT NULL AND column > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the question right, you can try:

```
IFNULL(column, 1) > 0
```

The `IFNULL` function returns the specified value if the expression is `NULL`, otherwise returns the expression itself.